# Is there any way to make this any more efficient?

Tags: python

Here is my program, it checks if you've passed all subjects, and as you guys can see, there are a lot of `if` conditions in it. I've read online that too many `if` conditions, or `for` loops can slow your program down, and that there is a more efficient way of doing it, that is by using some user-defined function.

How can I shrink my code down, and maybe make it more efficient?

````
# Take input
while True:
 a = float(input("Enter your mark in Tamil: "));
 b = float(input("Enter your mark in English: "));
 c = float(input("Enter your mark in Chemistry: "));
 d = float(input("Enter your mark in Physics: "));
 e = float(input("Enter your mark in Non-major: "));
 f = float(input("Enter your mark in Python: "));
# This part checks if you've got a minimum of 35% in every subject
 if a >= 35.0 and a <= 100.0:
  print("Pass in Tamil")
 if a > 100.0:
  print("Invalid input")
 if a < 35.0:
  print("Fail in Tamil")
 if b >= 35.0 and b <= 100.0:
  print("Pass in English")
 if b > 100.0:
  print("Invalid input")
 if b < 35.0:
  print("Fail in English")
 if c >= 35.0 and c <= 100.0:
  print("Pass in Chemistry")
 if c > 100.0:
  print("Invalid input")
 if c < 35.0:
  print("Fail in Chemistry")
 if d >= 35.0 and d <= 100.0:
  print("Pass in Physics")
 if d > 100.0:
  print("Invalid input")
 if d < 35.0:
  print("Fail in Physics")
 if e >= 35.0 and e <= 100.0:
  print("Pass in Non-major")
 if e > 100.0:
  print("Invalid input")
 if e < 35.0:
  print("Fail in Non-major")
 if f >= 35.0 and f <= 100.0:
  print("Pass in Python")
 if f > 100.0:
  print("Invalid input")
 if f < 35.0:
  print("Fail in Python")
# Display the total marks and the percentage secured by the user
 if (a>100 or b>100 or c>100 or d>100 or e>100 or f>100):
  print("Check your marks")
 if (a<=100 and b<=100 and c<=100 and d<=100 and e<=100 and f<=100):
  print("Your total:", a+b+c+d+e+f)
  print("Your percentage:", ((a+b+c+d+e+f)/600)*100)
# Check if the user wants to do another calculation 
 next_calculation = input("Do you want to proceed with next calculation? (yes/no) ")
 if next_calculation == "no":
  break
 if next_calculation != ("yes" or "no"):
  print("Invalid input")
  break```
````

Comment: the best way to do is to read a book or a take a tutorial/course about it, not ask people online to rewrite it for you, please read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Hi, @Kavin Nath... We've all been there (Well... I think... I know **I** have) I would invite you to consider reading about dictionaries, lists and how to iterate them (particularly with `for` loops). One thing that comes to mind is that you could create a `dict` where the subject names are its keys and the marks are its values. Then you could iterate over them and do your checks on a pair of (`CourseName, Mark)` basis. Also, you might be interested in the [Code Review community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In addition to the comments by @Kevin Nath, if you are running python 3.10+ look at using the match functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use functions

You're doing input, output (print) and if-then statements. You even have comments in your code, explaining what you're doing.

Next step is to decompose your code into logical functions. I see that your comments are already pointing in the right direction (for example: "Take input" does exactly that). Now create a function (`def function_name(function_arguments):`) and think about what that function needs as input (function arguments) and what it should output (`return` value). For example in your code, you could have the following functions:

- Ask the user for marks for a class. Input: class name. Output: a valid mark.
- Print if the user failed or passed. Input: class name, mark.

You can create functions that perform this task. This cuts your code input (re)usable and manageable pieces. Add a comment at the beginning of the function that describes what it does.

### Learn about `list`s and `dict`s

Lists and Dicts (dictionaries) are extremely useful datatypes in Python. Learn them. I included them in the example below. More (general) info on lists, dicts, sets, etc. in [the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) or [anywhere on the web](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-data-types/).

### Code style: PEP8

Try to code according to general accepted styling rules, called [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Most important examples (for you as a beginner):

- Give your variables meaningful names (not: `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.).
- Don't use "magic numbers" in your code (0, 35, 100, 'yes', etc.). Create constants, define them at the top of the module, give them names in capitals (`MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42`).
- Use 4 spaces as identation (not 1).

### "More efficient" version of your code

Here is a rewrite of your code. I tried to keep it simple and meaningful for you.

```python
MIN_MARK = 0.0
PASS_MARK = 35.0
MAX_MARK = 100.0
YES = ['yes', 'y']


def get_marks(classname: str) -> float:
    """ Asks a mark for the given classname.
        Checks the mark for a numeric value and
        that the mark is between MIN_MARK and MAX_MARK (both included)
    """
    while True:
        mark = input(f'Enter your mark in {classname}: ')

        if mark.isnumeric():
            mark = float(mark)
            if mark >= MIN_MARK and mark <= MAX_MARK:
                return mark
            else:
                print(f'Enter a mark between 0 and 100; please try again!')
        else:
            print(f'{mark} is not a valid numeric value; please try again!')


def print_pass_or_fail(classname: str, mark: float) -> None:
    """ Prints if classname is passed or failed. 
        Class if passed if mark >= PASS_MARK.
    """
    if mark > PASS_MARK:
        result = 'PASS'
    else:
        result = 'FAIL'

    print(f'{result} in {classname} with scoe {mark}')


def main():
    classes = ['Tamil', 'English', 'Chemistry',
               'Physics', 'Non-major', 'Python']
    marks = {}
    proceed = True

    while proceed:
        for classname in classes:
            marks[classname] = get_marks(classname)

        for classname, grade in marks.items():
            print_pass_or_fail(classname, grade)

        print(f'Totale score: {sum(marks.values())}')
        print(f'Average score: {sum(marks.values()) / len(marks) * 100}%')

        proceed = input('Continue [y/n]')
        proceed = proceed.lower() in YES


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRha9swEP2uX3ErDMejTT26biNbCqF0ULaWsPbDRilGjS@xVlsOktxgQn57dpJtOU5K/cWW9e7p7t07LSuTFvJsu725vo1vJr9/whiiYcSmk7u7dn12Tj9uJn/a9cfIIv5e3dH3Q1ChDo4hqIJHxliCc1igiXOunvVglnGtJc9xBNqoEE4uYJ4V3IwY0HN0dAQT/ayBg4XDvFBgUoSFeEEJPnbowPa5THFGcIvxARxkmaMSM3jhWYnAZeLxJuWmQwsNT2hWSNy@VkKDL2zwVJgUhJxlZYJJ2Obo3qtUZAj3qsSRp3esYwpYlmYwD66kQQVVUarmPAlrX8RmBEHIfKiYO8xQ6Cb7Qdjx7nA7tQZ2Efa2m3i4GPdrcT@/j31NfVL7KDSlkg7Y28NM4yF6qYTsamv61KoYuSPJDN9gmSHXCEZVwBdcyHdBl@8hc8u6tnQb2xhZGGKnDoqk38/XqWufOZp4SQrHhYrnXGR7hjt2@Y5qFZ37bguJnfmmlkBbMX2cTcYyYgJkLsuJyRA6B1qcDWgwO33wAzPsGccjOkAnhkJdZob6HNjNgB3K1SF@TK5/BbWDvH717mbParAS5GM9KxBqhb1iOenXOs3hUbsRvue5yOwQX8lFJnRqP2nYckEiVsHxvi2CaVppMXNjT4qe5Pxfoexi6i4TughaC1v69aZJupghSTZ2U8R2pqrZ6Yq2c73TEdnmejgi@sHjHon5lZtnZ@h6tMewUDxx7C5iKAzmen8M37JYw7BzQNuX@8Jwqos6oMiIa13mg/oMZ2k6JNzszEcbNXlBxRdvhsEpZCjrvyF8sLO3eR/0MmhFrm@l4LKQRki6Fx@qU/nYO7VFNl/DrFihGoRWEbrayTFk3Ti2lcYxjMmBcWz9E8fBqOmvNRPbbs8i9ili5xH7HLEvEfsaMfkf)

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for answering my question. It was really helpful. I'll definitely follow your advice in my future works.

Answer (score 1):

```
while int(input("Do you want to proceed with next calculation? '1' - yes, 0 - 'no': ")):
       
    d = {i:float(input(f"Enter your mark in {i}: ")) for i in ['Tamil', 'English', 'Chemistry', 'Physics', 'Non-major', 'Python']}

    l = [f"Pass in {k}" if 35 <=v <= 100 else ("Invalid input" if v>100 else f"Fail in {k}") for k,v in d.items()]

    # This part checks if you've got a minimum of 35% in every subject
    for i in l:
        print(i)

    # Display the total marks and the percentage secured by the user
    if 'Invalid input' in l:
        print('Check your marks')
    else:
        print("Your total: ", sum(d.values()))
        print("Your percentage: ", sum(d.values())/600*100)

    print("\n",'*'*40,'\n\n\n')

print('see you later!')
```